# What is the correct input voltage for the 9v Lego train speed regulator?

Tags: power-functions, electronics, 9v

I wanted to buy a transformer for the [speed regulator](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=2868b), so based on [this image](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemPic.asp?P=70931), I bought a transformer with 12V DC output. It works.

However, discussing this with a fellow AFOL, he pointed out that his (original from LEGO) transformer has a 10V AC output, as seen in [this image](http://brickowl.com/catalog/lego-transformer-for-9-volt-products-with-120-volt-input-45541).

So... which one is correct? Or they both work? Or there are different versions of the speed regulator with different input requirements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My speed regulator is clearly labeled as being 9-12V AC. I have an official 12VAC transformer.

[image: controller back]

I was curious about the internals of this device, so I opened it up:

[image: pcb top]

[image: pcb bottom]

The circuit begins with 4 diodes in standard [bridge rectifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_rectifier) configuration. This converts the AC input into a rippled DC voltage. The large capacitor (2200uF, 25V) then cleans up the ripples. There is also an [LM317](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LM317) adjustable voltage regulator configured to output various voltages depending on the dial setting.

This means that the input can be 9-12 voltes AC or DC because the rectifier simply passes DC current.